# I keep getting a seg fault not sure why

Tags: c, matrix, struct

This code is to make and print a matrix out but i am not sure why i am getting seg fault, it is because I am not freeing memory, if so how would i free it?

```
void printMatrix(struct Matrix *M){
  struct Matrix *temp = M;
  for(int i=0; i< temp->rows;i++){
    for(int j=0; j< temp->cols;j++){
      printf("%.f",getVal(temp,i,j));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
void makeMatrix(struct Matrix *M, int row, int col, int num){
   M = malloc(sizeof(struct Matrix));
  M->rows=row;
  M->cols=col;
  M->m =malloc(100*sizeof(double)*M->rows*M->cols);
  for(int i=0; i<M->rows;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<M->cols;j++){
        setVal(M,i,j,num);
    }
  }
  free(M);
}
int  main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  struct Matrix *test;
  makeMatrix(test,10,10,10);
  printMatrix(test);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `test` has not been assigned a value, it has garbage, you cannot print it.. Remember: in C all arguments are passed by value (*what happens in the other function, stays in the other function*)

Comment: Remember that in C arguments are passed *by value*. That means the value in the call is copied into the functions local argument variable. Any modifications to the argument variable (like assigning to it) will only happen to the local argument variable. Either *return* the new value or do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Also be careful when and where you delete the matrix. And make sure that *all* `malloc` calls have a corresponding call to `free` (which your code doesn't have).

Comment: And in `100*sizeof(double)*M->rows*M->cols`, why multiply with `100`?

Comment: There are some definitions missing from your question but perhaps [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jrE53dnTK) would be a more complete approach.

Comment: Main issue is found in the linked duplicate. But obviously it doesn't make any sense to `free(M)` from the allocation function either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `makeMatrix` function is wrong. Parameter `M` is a **local** variable when `makeMatrix` executed. Thereofre any changes to `M` are **not** visible when the function ends. As result `test` is not initialized when passed to `printMatrix` causing failure then the pointer is dereferenced.

The solution is returning `M` from the function by value.

```
struct Matrix *makeMatrix(int row, int col, int num){
  struct Matrix *M = malloc(sizeof(struct Matrix));
  if (!M) return NULL;
  M->rows=row;
  M->cols=col;
  M->m =malloc(100*sizeof(double)*M->rows*M->cols);
  if (!M->m) {
    free(M);
    return NULL;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<M->rows;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<M->cols;j++){
        setVal(M,i,j,num);
    }
  }
  return M;
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Matrix *test = makeMatrix(10,10,10);
```

Moreover, `malloc(100*sizeof(double)*M->rows*M->cols);` looks a bit wasteful because it consumes 100x more memory than needed. I'm pretty sure that `malloc(sizeof(double)*M->rows*M->cols);` would suffice.

Comment: so what does the if statement do this solved my problem but I am not sure what is the point of the if(), also just for clarification when I make a pointer as a paramter the life span is only within the paramter right ?

Comment: @ShehabA, because `malloc` may fail. The validity of the returned pointer is checked by `!M` ("not" + pointer). The lifespan of the parameter ends when `return` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

First, always have to check if the malloc successfully allocates memory. So after the first call to `malloc`, you should write something like that:

```
    if(!M)
    {
        printf("malloc failed to allocate memory for M");
        return;
    }
```

and so on. Also you should free each memory space you allocated with `malloc`. In your case you should also `free(M->m)`